# How to add custom rewrite rules and point to specific templates

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

How can I add a custom rewrite rule so I can catch paths like these:

```
/products/imports/filters
/products/imports/elements
/products/imports/parts
```

And point them to a template file, for examples:

```
sector.php
```

My code:

```
function sector_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '(.?.+?)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&sector=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'sector_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

But I get 404 when I tried with the URLs above.

I have created a standard page called `imports` created under `products` already:

```
products/
   imports/
```

So I want to catch any word right after this page:

```
/products/imports/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create `query_var` for `sector` and you need to create a rewrite rule with RegEX. I created a plugin for this. Create a file and add into the `wp-content/plugins` folder and activate it.

```php
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Custom Rewrite
Plugin URI: https://serkanalgur.com.tr
Description: Custom Rewrite
Version: 1
Author: Serkan Algur
Author URI: https://www.serkanalgur.com.tr
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

class FilterRewriteRule
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->InitRewriteRules();
        add_filter('query_vars', [$this,'add_query_for_sector']);
        add_filter('template_include', array($this, 'filter_template'), 99);
    }

    private function add_query_for_sector($vars)
    {
        $vars[] = 'sector';
        return $vars;
    }

    private function InitRewriteRules()
    {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            'products/import/([^/]*)/?$',
            'index.php?pagename=products/import&sector=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );

        add_rewrite_rule(
            'products/import/page/([0-9]{1,})/([^/]*)/?$',
            'index.php?paged=$matches[1]&pagename=products/import&sector=$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );
    }

    public function filter_template($template)
    {
        global $wp;
        if (get_query_var('sector') && is_page('import')) {
            $custom_template = locate_template('sector.php');
            if ($custom_template) {
                return $custom_template;
            }
        }
        return $template;
    }
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, function () {
    $writing_ideas = new FilterRewriteRule();
    $writing_ideas->init();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
});
```

`add_rewrite_rule` add the rewrite rule with pagination support. `filter_template` locate your `sector.php` file and redirect the request to this file. `query_vars` adds `sector` query to WordPress system.

Comment: thanks. it works with fixed prefixed `'products/imports/([^/]*)/?$',` . I need to make this bit `products/imports/` dynamic...

Comment: You are welcome. You can change first `products/imports/([^/]*)/?$` to `([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$` and `index.php?pagename=products/import&sector=$matches[1]` to `index.php?pagename=$matches[1]t&sector=$matches[2]` but, that can be effect WordPress base rewrite rules. Please be careful when you change rewrite rules.

Answer (score 2):

### An alternate Solution

If you're concerned about the Page slug being changed later on, then you could instead use [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/), but this means the URL would need an extra path, e.g. `/sector` as in `example.com/products/imports/sector/filters`.

So the steps are identical, except that you no longer need to manually hook on `query_vars` because `add_rewrite_endpoint()` will, by default, do that automatically for you:

1. Register the `sector` endpoint for all Pages:

   ```php
   add_action( 'init', 'my_sector_init' );
   function my_sector_init() {
       add_rewrite_endpoint( 'sector', EP_PAGES );
   }
   ```

   Remember to remove the `add_action('init', 'sector_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);` in your code.. and as I already said before, flush the rewrite rules! :)
2. Load the `sector.php` template on those custom endpoint pages:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'page_template', 'my_sector_page_template' );
   function my_sector_page_template( $template ) {
       if ( get_query_var( 'sector' ) ) {
           $template = locate_template( 'sector.php' );
       }

       return $template;
   }
   ```

### Other Option when using `add_rewrite_rule()` with a specific Page slug or path

Store the Page ID in a variable (or database option if you want to) and the previous path in a post metadata, and whenever the Page *or its parent* is updated, specifically if the slug is changed, then you can *programmatically flush the rewrite rules*.

So based on my original answer, in step 1, we'll call [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/) **only if applicable**:

```php
function sector_rewrite_rule() {
    $page_id = 123;

    // Ensure that the post exists.
    if ( ! get_post( $page_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $post_ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $page_id );
    $previous_slug  = get_post_meta( $page_id, '_prev_path', true );

    // Build the hierarchical path.
    $post_ancestors[] = $page_id;
    $current_slug = implode( '/', array_map( function ( $id ) {
            return get_post_field( 'post_name', $id );
    }, $post_ancestors ) );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^' . preg_quote( $current_slug ) . '/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?page_id=' . $page_id . '&sector=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

    global $pagenow; // this is defined on admin pages
    if ( 'options-permalink.php' !== $pagenow && $current_slug !== $previous_slug ) {
        update_post_meta( $page_id, '_prev_path', $current_slug );
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}
```

And step 2 remains the same, but step 3 would be (note the `$page_id`):

```php
add_filter( 'page_template', 'my_sector_page_template' );
function my_sector_page_template( $template ) {
    $page_id = 123;

    if ( is_page( $page_id ) && get_query_var( 'sector' ) ) {
        $template = locate_template( 'sector.php' );
    }

    return $template;
}
```

So you can try those and just replace the value of `$page_id` with the correct ID.

Comment: thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps, which worked well for me:

1. Use a more specific rewrite rule RegEx pattern like so which ensures the current URL *path* is in the form of `products/imports/<word>`:

   ```php
   function sector_rewrite_rule() {
       add_rewrite_rule(
           // matches products/imports/filters, but not products/imports/filters/foo
           '^products/imports/([^/]+)/?$',

           // ensure pagename is in the form of <parent>/<child>
           'index.php?pagename=products/imports&sector=$matches[1]',

           'top'
       );
   }
   ```
2. Register `sector` as a public query var via the [`query_vars` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/): (public query vars are those that will be read from GET/URL and POST parameters)

   ```php
   add_filter( 'query_vars', 'sector_query_vars' );
   function sector_query_vars( $vars ) {
       $vars[] = 'sector';

       return $vars;
   }
   ```
3. Now that the rewrite rule and query var has been both added, we just need to ensure the `sector.php` template is used on the `products/imports/<word>` endpoints. So since we're targeting a Page (post of type `page`), then I'm using the [`page_template` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/), but you could instead use the [`template_include` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) if you want to:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'page_template', 'my_sector_page_template' );
   function my_sector_page_template( $template ) {
       if ( is_page( 'imports' ) && get_query_var( 'sector' ) ) {
           // this assumes the template is in the active theme directory
           // and just change the path if the template is somewhere else
           $template = locate_template( 'sector.php' ); // use a full absolute path
       }

       return $template;
   }
   ```

Remember to flush the rewrite rules after you're done with step 1 above! Just visit the Permalink Settings page without having to click on the Save Changes button.

Also, if you need to support pagination (e.g. `products/imports/filters/page/2`), then you'd need to adjust the above rewrite rule RegEx pattern **and** query for that.

Comment: thanks. it works with a fixed prefixed `'products/imports/([^/]*)/?$',` . I need to make this bit `products/imports/` dynamic... because the slug can be changed by someone who manages the contents

Comment: Yes, I actually did noticed that. But anyway, I've added another answer, so I hope the solutions there would also help you. Happy coding!